# Make django dev server capture anything except home page

Tags: django, nginx

**nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)

Django 1.8.4**

It's the first time I have deployed anything on a live web server.
The hoster provides me with an ip address and a technical domain name for it.

At this time all that I want is just to use Django development webserber to show the site working. This is just for myself, not a real website.
Later on everything will be via gunicorn.

In /etc/nginx/sites-available/default:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;

    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
    }

}
```

Then in Django project:

**In urls.py**

```
from lists import views as list_views
from lists import urls as list_urls

urlpatterns = [
    #url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$', list_views.home_page, name="home"),
    url(r'^lists/', include(list_urls)),
    ]

**In lists/urls.py**

from lists import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^new$', views.new_list, name='new_list'),    
    url(r'^(\d+)/$', views.view_list, name='view_list' ),    
    url(r'^(\d+)/add_item$', views.add_item, name='add_item'),    
    ]

**lists/views.py**

import logging

def home_page(request):
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.error('In home_page')


def view_list(request, list_id):
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.error('In view_list')


def new_list(request):
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.error('In new_list')
```

Then when I go to my site via the ip address or via the technical link, I can see the home page.

But when I go to /lists/new, I catch 404 in the browser. As well as

```
nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
```

This means that Django server wasn't even informed. And checking the log proves that. No message "In new_list". Definitely Django dev server didn't capture the signal here.

How can I cope with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check if your Django project runs well, you don't need Nginx. Just `./manage.py runserver example.com:8000` and access your site via `http://example.com:8000`. If the port isn't open, you could also stop Nginx with `service nginx stop` and then run Django on port :80.

---

This setting seems to tell Nginx to try and see if the file exists and to return HTTP 404 if it doesn't. I don't think it ever gets to the second line.

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
}
```

Try and remove the "try_files" line and add extra `location` rules for the static files you want to serve.

```
location /static/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
}
```